# Is there any way to apply .emacs changes to all emacs clients without restarting emacs daemon?

Tags: emacs, config, daemon, restart, emacsclient

I started emacs server through 'emacs --daemon'.
Then I opened several clients.

I'd like to apply the changes of .emacs configuration to all the clients without restarting emacs daemon.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

Changes don't get applied to the clients, they get applied to the server.

You just use clients to interact with the server.

So simply re-evaluate your init file changes in any one of your clients.

Anything that doesn't doesn't appear to have taken effect is unlikely to be a client/server issue, and more likely to be some more general frame/terminal/buffer-local issue. That's going to be entirely dependent on the specific elisp that you're re-evaluating, though (so you should post details if necessary).